# PHP From string to two variables

Tags: php, mysql

In my db there is a table that have some values like this[string]

```
100/100
50/100
40/80
7/70
```

I need to change this values in

```
100%
50%
50%
10%
```

How can i do this using only PHP/mysql code?

EDIT:this is the code:

```
foreach ($html->find('div.stat') as $status_raw){
    $status = $tag_pic_raw->src;
    $status = mysql_real_escape_string($status);
    $data->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `tb` (`value`) VALUES ('".$status."')");
}
```

I have used a DOM inspector to get info from another site

Comment: can you show the database/php code that you have already written ?

Comment: And now as we sit and wait patiently for the verdict...

Comment: @Zenmaru [don't forget to reward the users that have helped you with your question and select one of the answer as the right answer, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: @Fred-ii- rather than asking for a verdict I believe the above is easier for new members.

Comment: @Prix I take it you don't know me very well ;-) I like to add a bit of "off the wall" or "slapstick" humour *as it were.* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- :P you need to throw that straight punch.

Comment: @Prix hahahaha! Nah... I'm rather nice about my comments. It helps to eleviate the humdrum routine.

Comment: What database layer are you using here? `$data->query` suggests something like PDO, which means `mysql_real_escape_string` has no business being here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `explode()` to divide up the values and then math them.

```
foreach($array as $val) // assuming all the (##/##) values are in an array
{
    $mathProblem = explode("/", $val);
    echo (intval($mathProblem[0]) / intval($mathProblem[1]) * 100)."%<br />";
}
```

Comment: another possibility is using `list($num, $den) = explode("/", $val);` which gives you two nice variables you can work with instead of indices

Comment: hadn't thought of that. clever way to make the code more aesthetically-pleasing/human-readable.

Answer (score 4):

Used `explode()` combined with some math.

```
$str = '40/80';
$vals = explode('/', $str);
$percent = (($vals[0] / $vals[1]) * 100).'%';
echo $percent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()`  :Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter( `/` in this case).

```
$arr=array('80/100','50/100','40/80');
foreach($arr as $str){
 $values = explode('/',$str);
 echo ((int)$values[0]/(int)$values[1])*100.'%<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a function similar to this:

```
function math($one)
    {
        $new = explode("/", $one);
        $math = $new[0] / $new[1];
        $answer = $math * 100;
        return $answer."%";
    }
```

Then every time you need to query something, you can do it simply by doing this:

```
foreach ($results as $r)
{
    echo math($r);
}
```

This just makes it (I think) tidier and easier to read.